# Access violation when allocating memory in exported C++ function in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllexport

I'm trying to prepare a trivial memory leak example in C++ for .NET developers. Thus I created a C++ dll (DevC++ 5.11 with gcc 4.9.2) , which is called from .NET Console application via PInvoke. Both projects are 64 bit. I'm able to call the exported method from .NET, even return value. But whenever I use new operator an Access violation exception is raised. I'm starting to get crazy, can you please advise what is wrong?

The C++ code (I have only 1 single file dllmain.cpp, containing only these lines, nothing else):

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int CalculateRandomNumber()
{    
     int*ptr_one;
     //ptr_one = new int[1000000];    //<---Uncommenting this will generate AccessViolation
     return 4;
};

Compiler output is:
Compiling project changes...
--------
- Project Filename: D:\MemoryLeakPresentation\c++\SmartDll.dev
- Compiler Name: TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release

Building makefile...
--------
- Filename: D:\MemoryLeakPresentation\c++\Makefile.win

Processing makefile...
--------
- Makefile Processor: C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin\mingw32-make.exe
- Command: mingw32-make.exe -f "D:\MemoryLeakPresentation\c++\Makefile.win" all

g++.exe -c dllmain.cpp -o dllmain.o -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++" -DBUILDING_DLL=1

g++.exe -shared dllmain.o -o SmartDll.dll -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib" -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib" -static-libgcc -Wl,--output-def,libSmartDll.def,--out-implib,libSmartDll.a,--add-stdcall-alias


Compilation results...
--------
- Errors: 0
- Warnings: 0
- Output Filename: D:\MemoryLeakPresentation\c++\SmartDll.dll
- Output Size: 366.10546875 KiB
- Compilation Time: 0.23s
```

and then I import it to C# like this. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Complete program looks like this:

```
class Program
{

    [DllImport(@"d:\MemoryLeakPresentation\c++\SmartDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int CalculateRandomNumber();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            int random =  CalculateRandomNumber();
            Console.WriteLine(random);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }

}
```

I honestly don't know what is going on and I don't have any additional information. The moment I uncomment memory allocation, it crashes :

**Unhandled exception at 0x0000000068214620 (SmartDll.dll) in 1_CallingCppCode.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFCA161F1B.**

Comment: I think the calling convention should be StdCall. according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention(v=vs.110).aspx that is the preferable calling convention when calling unmanaged code.

Comment: `__cdecl` is default for the C++. Have you tried calling your dll from the unmanaged code? Will AV happen?

Comment: Exported convention matches with imported, and I tried stdcall with the same outcome. When called from C++ console application, it behaves correctly.

Comment: What you describe is not very plausible. I for one don't believe you. I think either your code isn't what you say it is, or there is some other missing information. How about a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, I'm just as confused as you are. I included additional information to the post about how the dll is compiled.